# Transform an xml containing a list of child nodes to separate xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml input which contains a list of xml child nodes. i want to separate this xml based on the xml child nodes. But while separating, the parent nodes need to be retained. I tried using for-each, But the output was not as expected.

Input

```
<node1>
   <id>1</id>
   <code>abcd</code>
   <version>v1</version>
   <node2>
      <market>india</market>
      <active>true</active>
   </node2>
   <node2>
      <market>US</market>
      <active>true</active>
   </node2>
   <mixins>
      <node3>
         <ref>MZ-SR-P004</ref>
         <type>Commercial</type>
      </node3>
   </mixins>
</node1>
```

Expected Output

```
<node1>
   <id>1</id>
   <code>abcd</code>
   <version>v1</version>
   <node2>
      <market>india</market>
      <active>true</active>
   </node2>
   <mixins>
      <node3>
         <ref>MZ-SR-P004</ref>
         <type>Commercial</type>
      </node3>
   </mixins>
</node1>
<node1>
   <id>1</id>
   <code>abcd</code>
   <version>v1</version>
   <node2>
      <market>US</market>
      <active>true</active>
   </node2>
   <mixins>
      <node3>
         <ref>MZ-SR-P004</ref>
         <type>Commercial</type>
      </node3>
   </mixins>
</node1>
```

Is it possible to do it using xslt. I tried the below XSLT transformation

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node2">
         <xsl:for-each select="node2">
            <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:for-each>    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My current output looks like below

Current xml output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node1>
   <id>1</id>
   1
   <code>abcd</code>
   abcd
   <version>v1</version>
   v1
   <mixins>
      <node3>
         <ref>MZ-SR-P004</ref>
         MZ-SR-P004
         <type>Commercial</type>
         Commercial
      </node3>
      <ref>MZ-SR-P004</ref>
      MZ-SR-P004
      <type>Commercial</type>
      Commercial
   </mixins>
   <node3>
      <ref>MZ-SR-P004</ref>
      MZ-SR-P004
      <type>Commercial</type>
      Commercial
   </node3>
   <ref>MZ-SR-P004</ref>
   MZ-SR-P004
   <type>Commercial</type>
   Commercial
</node1>


 <id>1</id>1
<code>abcd</code>abcd
<version>v1</version>v1


<mixins>
  <node3>
     <ref>MZ-SR-P004</ref>MZ-SR-P004
     <type>Commercial</type>Commercial
  </node3>
     <ref>MZ-SR-P004</ref>MZ-SR-P004
     <type>Commercial</type>Commercial

</mixins>
  <node3>
     <ref>MZ-SR-P004</ref>MZ-SR-P004
     <type>Commercial</type>Commercial
  </node3>
     <ref>MZ-SR-P004</ref>MZ-SR-P004
     <type>Commercial</type>Commercial
```

Comment: can you show us both what output you do have now, and then also exactly what you want to have?

Comment: Can you also show us your current attempt with `xsl:for-each`. It might not be working, but you might not actually be far off. Thank you.

Comment: This is what i tried. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="d">
      <xsl:for-each select="d">
       <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding code in comments.

Comment: edited the question with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template matching `node2` you then do a `xsl:for-each` to select `node2` but that would be looking for child elements of the current `node2` you are matching, so nothing will be selected.

Your template should probably select `node1`. Then, within the `xsl:for-each` you need to create the `node1` and copy all child nodes that are either the current `node2` or a differently named node

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node1">
        <xsl:for-each select="node2">
            <node1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[generate-id() = generate-id(current()) or not(self::node2)]" />
            </node1>
        </xsl:for-each>    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note I also removed `<xsl:apply-templates />` from the identity template.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic XSLT 2 or 3 approach would be to select the nodes (e.g. `node1/node2`) and then to push the complete tree through a mode doing an identity copy with a tunnel parameter storing the current `node2` to ensure when that mode matches on `node2` it only outputs this particular `node2` and ignores all others:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:mode name="reconstruct" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="node1/node2">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="reconstruct">
            <xsl:with-param name="copy" tunnel="yes" select="current()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node2" mode="reconstruct">
      <xsl:param name="copy" tunnel="yes"/>
      <xsl:sequence select=".[. is $copy]"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJF